Stop minikube on Ubuntu shutdown
I'm new to Kubernetes, I have internal instruction on how to setup the app locally using minikube. The problem is that I sometimes forget to stop the Cluster, if I do when shutdown the system it will not get up again. I need to setup it again.
So I was wondering if there is maybe a way to crate simple script in background that will get signal when shutdown to stop the minikube.
Is something like this possible? I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

You can write a systemd unit that will start up minikube when your system boots, and will stop minikube when your system shuts down. It is possible to have it only perform the shutdown action if you prefer.

@larsks Thanks. Do you know how to do this? It would help people that search the same thing. If not, then I will need to search or ask ChatGPT how to do this and add my own answer.

There are many answers here and also on [unix.se] that show you how write systemd units. For writing something that runs explicitly at shutdown, see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/how-to-run-a-script-with-systemd-right-before-shutdown, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/739363/a-systemd-service-that-runs-just-before-shutdown-and-uses-a-mounted-filesystem, etc.
